# todonotes - listoftodos always outdated?

Tags: miktex, todonotes

I am using the package [todonotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) and its command `\missingfigure` to indicate where to place missing graphics for another editor of a user manual.

Unfortunately it seems that the `\listoftodos` only ever contains the entries from one build removed, not from the current build.

**How can I make it display the *current* issues with their *current* descriptions without building twice in a row?**
(And is this a bug I should report or simply user error?)

Additional info:

- using todonotes 1.1.7 on MiKTeX 24.1, Windows 10 x64
- This issue seems to be absent from the respective 'Known Issues' section of the [package manual](https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf).
- `\todo` behaves like `missingfigure`: It only shows up in the list after building twice and changing the TODO is only reflected in the list two builds after the change.
- I tried to place the list both at the beginning and at the end of the document - it behaves the same way in both cases.

At the top of the document (the most convenient position for collaboration):

```
[setup]

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\listoftodos
\tableofcontents

\frontmatter

[etc.]
```

At the bottom of the document (the position used in all examples I found online):

```
[...]

The following symbol(s) may appear on the \product:
\missingfigure{WARNING - Refer to manual}
\missingfigure{WARNING - Hot surface}

% This is incidentally where I stopped writing, because I noticed this issue.

\listoftodos
\end{document}
```

Just in case this is a package conflict, here is the setup I use:

```
% 'memoir' was suggested as a good class for printing; no idea whether that is approprate
% - I have not been using anything but scrartcl for what feels like a decade.
% plan: drop 'oneside' for print; 'openany' seems to have no effect though
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfig}
% the only one I have added myself so far
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}
```

Most of this comes from the MiKTeX template 'Basic LaTeX documents | article', I have made some minor tweaks though - most prominently to the documentclass - and would like to tweak it further later on.

Comment: Unrelated, memoir does not have a fontsize option, booktabs and verbatim is already loaded by memoir and fancyhdr should not be used with memoir.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling? Are you deleting files between compilations? I'd always expect todonotes to need at least two compilations (at least). If your document dies something strange, please provide a full minimal example others can copy and reproduce the issue on their own

Comment: you must compile twice. There is no way around that.